# .NET Core IHttpContextAccessor issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, c#-6.0

I have static helper class

```
public static class Current
{
    public static string Host
    {
        get { return "httpContextAccessor here"; }
    }
}
```

**How I can get access to current HttpContext inside Host property?**

Comment: Note that the HttpContext is part of ASP.NET Core rather than .NET Core.

Answer (score 7):

You can't and you shouldn't. This beats the whole purpose of having a dependency injection system at all. Static classes (for runtime data or Service Locator) is an anti-pattern.

In ASP.NET Core you have to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` in classes where you need it. You can make a non-static class and do something along the lines of:

```
public class RequestInformation : IRequestInformation
{
    private readonly HttpContext context;

    public RequestInformation(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) 
    {
        // Don't forget null checks
        this.context = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }

    public string Host
    {
        get { return this.context./*Do whatever you need here*/; }
    }
}
```

and in your class library inject it:

```
public class SomeClassInClassLibrary
{
    private readonly IRequestInformation requestInfo;

    public SomeClassInClassLibrary(IRequestInfomation requestInfo) 
    {
        // Don't forget null checks
        this.requestInfo = requestInfo;

        // access it
        var host = requestInfo.Host;
    }
}
```

Be aware that your `SomeClassInClassLibrary` must be resolved with either `Scoped` or `Transient` mode and it can't be `Singleton`, because `HttpContext` is only valid for the duration of the request.

Alternatively if `SomeClassInClassLibrary` has to be singleton, you have to inject a factory and resolve the `IRequestInformation` on demand (i.e. inside an action).

Last but not least, `IHttpContextAccessor` isn't registered by default.

> IHttpContextAccessor can be used to access the HttpContext for the current thread. However, maintaining this state has non-trivial performance costs so it has been removed from the default set of services.
>
> Developers that depend on it can add it back as needed:
>   `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

Source: [The IHttpContextAccessor service is not registered by default](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/190#issue-159298966)