# Why should I inject IHttpContextAccessor as a Singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, httpcontext

In all examples that i've seen of `IHttpContextAccessor` injection, it is set as a Singleton.

Examples:

[How to add IHttpContextAccessor in the Startup class in the DI in ASP.NET Core 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184583/how-to-add-ihttpcontextaccessor-in-the-startup-class-in-the-di-in-asp-net-core-1)
[Injecting IHttpContextAccessor into ApplicationDbContext ASP.NET Core 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131925/injecting-ihttpcontextaccessor-into-applicationdbcontext-asp-net-core-1-0)
[.NET Core IHttpContextAccessor issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40303982/net-core-ihttpcontextaccessor-issue)

I find it kinda weird, since `HttpContext` really looks like something that maps to requests. Wouldn't `AddScoped` be more appropriate in this case?

Is Singleton really the recomended way? Am I not seeeing something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is Singleton really the recomended way?

**Yes**

According to comments associated with an issue raised on GitHub

https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793#issuecomment-224828588

> > In that sample, you are registering it as a singleton. Shouldn't it be a scoped instance?
>
> It's fine being a singleton because the backing store is async local.

Which got a later reply

https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793#issuecomment-224924030

> Actually if you register it as a Transient on .NET Core then it doesn't work properly since the implementation for .NET Core is using a AsyncLocal which relies upon the instance variable to track the thread local storage slot. So it has to be registered as a singleton on .NET Core.

Comment: I dont understand this statement at all: " .NET Core is using a AsyncLocal which relies upon the instance variable to track the TLS storage slot". But the question was answered! thanks.

Comment: I totally disagree with this answer. async local should be avoided and request scope should be the clean and efficient way to go. See here for a simple and effective solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966858/scoped-service-access-http-context-without-ihttpcontextaccessor

Comment: "backing store is async local": is this mean, that the accessor will have a singleton instance by thread (plus handles correctly the thread switches what happen when request serving thread uses async an magically continues in an other thread?)

Comment: The "later reply" is no longer valid
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/commit/622d112372ed11075af160b1fb5a11a7637ff516#commitcomment-69899284