# Scoped service: Access HTTP context without IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core I have a service that is registered in DI as scoped. Can I access the HTTP context in that service **without** using `IHttpContextAccessor` and the overhead it has?

Comment: What's the `overhead`?

Answer (score 8):

You'd have to add a scoped service to the container, then you'd have to add a middleware that resolved that service and set the current http context on it.

```
public class ScopedHttpContext
{
    public HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ScopedHttpContext>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ScopedHttpContextMiddleware>();
}

public class ScopedHttpContextMiddleware 
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ScopedHttpContextMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ScopedHttpContext scopedContext)
    {
        scopedContext.HttpContext = context;
        return _next(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a step in the right direction, David! Is direct constructor injection not possible? I won't know in advance whether I need the service or not.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? This is the cope to prepare the ScopedHttpContext in the first place. Once you do this, you can inject ScopedHttpContext into the constructors of scoped services (assuming it gets set before you resolve)

Comment: Hi  @davidfowl , I used a similar approach to what u suggested in your answer. in my project.
But then i need to make sure that all classes using this object have to be scoped.
This caused an issue when i need to perform Task.Run and the scoped classes gets disposed but background logic using them keeps running. Any suggestions around this.

Comment: It is possible in versions of ASP.NET Core that support IMiddleware.