# Cannot consume scoped service 'IHttpContextAccessor' from singleton 'IMyCustomThing'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I am getting an error like this:

> Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' from singleton 'MyNamespace.IMyCustomThing'

I am confused, because I register `IHttpContextAccessor` by calling `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`.  The code for AddHttpContextAccessor is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/425c196cba530b161b120a57af8f1dd513b96f67/src/Http/Http/src/HttpServiceCollectionExtensions.cs).  The relevant part is this:

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

**IHttpContextAccessor is registered as a singleton.  Why does ASP.Net Core think it is a scoped service?**

NOTE: Incase it is relevant, `IMyCustomThing` uses the `IHttpContextAccessor` to see if there is a current `HttpContext`, if there is not then it takes other actions.

Comment: Which scope's `IHttpContextAccessor` instance should it give to your singleton `IMyCustomThing`?

Comment: @madreflection - That makes it make perfect sense (now).  Not sure why the source code shows this registered as a singleton, but it really can't work as one.  I could have 10 calls going at once, I would need someway to say which one I mean when I ask for an HttpContext.  If the call comes from a singleton, then that is not really possible.

Comment: @madreflection - though looking at this quesiton/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330007/why-should-i-inject-ihttpcontextaccessor-as-a-singleton It seems to indicate that it uses an `AsyncLocal` to tell which HttpContext it will return.  So it should be able to work as a Singleton.  And it registers as one.  (I am again confused why it would to that yet through the above error.)

Comment: `AsyncLocal` gets the context, but we're talking about the context *accessor* here. It looks like the context accessor can be registered as a singleton but something is mistakenly registering it as scoped. What happens if you don't call `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()`? Same error (i.e. something else is registering it) or an error about the service not being registered?

Comment: @madreflection - That was it!  I found this evil line lurking in a method:  `services.AddScoped<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>()`.    Once I removed that the error went away!  If you want to post as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As we sussed out in the comments, you have something registering `IHttpContextAccessor` as a scoped service.  Remove that.

`services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` registers it as a singleton as it's designed to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad I could provide it.